# android handler .postdelay() everytime minute change on clock?

Tags: java, android, handler

i want to delay post till the minute change on clock.
currently i am using this

```
handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 60000);
```

but this delay post 60 seconds from the time right now.
what i want to do is
delay the post till minute change on the clock.

**for example:** lets say time on my phone is `4:15:29` than i want to delay it till the time `4:16:00` and then the next is `4:17:00` and so on.

is there anyway to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the current time by:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

After you have that, you can get the second part of it by:

```
int seconds = new Date(time).getSeconds();
```

Then you can substract that from 60, and get the sleep time.

```
int sleepSecs = 60 - seconds;
```

Then set that to sleep time to `handler.postDelayed()`

```
handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, sleepSecs*1000);
```

After the first time you use this, you can use a constant 60000 millisecond sleeptime.

**Please note, that getSeconds() can return 60 or 61 as second value! [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getSeconds%28%29)**

Comment: do u know how can i change that postDelayed time to again , like suppose i have set 4000ms sec and now 2000ms pass , now i want to set new interval time like it should be 7000ms , how can i do ? do u know ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617453/best-way-to-)  Timer class to schedule periodic task this way you can change your Clock time in any period of time as you need.