# How can repeating AlarmManager start AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

I usually write this code to start a service with `AlarmManager`.

```
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), someservice.class);
    pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
    alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 30 * 1000;
    long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now, interval, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

My `AsyncTask` is a private class where I register `AlarmManager` object.

How can I call the `AsyncTask` instead of a service using `AlarmManager` object?

PS. If there is a better way to run `AsyncTask` every X seconds/minutes, please propose it!

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why? Do you have a particular reason why you need an `AsyncTask` instead of a `Service`?

Comment: @kabuko This task is supposed to work ONLY if app is open (UI is visible) so there is no purpose of using the service and double coding when I can simply call already existing `AsyncTask`. I know I can use `Timer`, but I am not sure if that is the proper way as it is not normally advised to use in repeating tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

1.) Define a static intent (intent1) and use it to pass to AlarmManager when setting time. So now when ever time, will lapse; AlarmManager will notify by sending intent1.

2.) On onReceive of BroadcastReceiver of intent1, start a AsyncTask. At end end of AsyncTask, set the next time for AlarmManager.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon [munish-katoch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751027/munish-katoch)'s response, I have the following concrete solution.

Set an alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

The above code configures `AlarmManager` to fire at `AlarmReceiver`, which is defined as follows:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
    new MyAsyncTask.execute();
  }
}
```

In the event of an alarm `AlarmReceiver` starts `MyAsyncTask`.

#### Here be dragons

There are [life cycle issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174226/is-instantiating-an-asynctask-from-a-wakefulbroadcastreceiver-recommended) associated with instantiating an `AsyncTask` from a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, i.e., the above solution can lead to `MyAsyncTask` being killed prematurely. Moreover, [threading rules are violated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172977/3664487).

Comment: The following question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750664/is-it-possible-to-use-asynctask-in-a-service-class/25298135