# Periodically Executing AsyncTask Class object: Updated

Tags: android

what is the best way to start AsyncTask again after it has completed.
My application is where I need to do some background processing that updates UI every 30 secs or so.

So will this be good

```
MyAsyncTask t;

onCreate(){
 postDelayed(myrunnable,..)
}

myrunnable(){
if(t && t.getStatus()== FINISHED){
t = new MyAsyncTask();
t.execute()

 postDelayed(myrunnable,30000)
}else
postDelayed(myrunnable,2000)
}
```

Update:Edited the code, So if this sequence seems valid please say yes or suggest changes

Comment: You question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617453/best-way-to-periodically-executing-asynctasks-in-android?rq=1

Comment: I have to use AsyncTask only not timers

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals)

Comment: I dont want it on main UI thread

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Register your class responsible of the AsyncTask execution as listener in your AsyncTask.
- Implement a callback in your AsyncTask when the task is finished at the end of the doInBackground method.
- Execute the next AsyncTask when you receive the callback.

Example:
Your listener interface:

```
public interface IProgress {

  public void onProgressUpdate(final boolean isFinished);

}
```

Your activity implements IProgress:

```
public class MyActivity implements IProgress {


  public void onProgressUpdate(final boolean isFinished) {

    if (isFinished) {
        // delayed execution
        myHandler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(MyActivity.this), 30000);
    }
  }
```

Your AsyncTask contains a IProgress instance and you call onProgressUpdate at the end of doInBackground or in onPostExecute:

...

```
  private final IProgress progressListener;

  public MyAsyncTask( final IProgress progressListener) {
    super();    
    this.progressListener = progressListener;    
  }
```

...

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final int result) {
    progressListener.onProgressUpdate(true);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
  }
```

Create a runnnable for the postDelayed:

```
  protected class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final IProgress progressListener;

    public MyRunnable(final IProgress progressListener) {
      super();
      this.progressListener= progressListener;
    }

    public void run() {
            new MyAsyncTask(progressListener).execute();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Async-task class within a specific time, like 30sec time interval.

You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.

Comment: AsyncTask is great and I would like to use it. What I dont understand is how to know that AysnTask is fully destoryed, before starting a new one.

Comment: @manish go through with this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html it will help u ...

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am reading it all day. No luck. There is no status field which I can check. Can you please point out to something specific

Comment: if ScheduledExecuotr is answer the i am not going that way