# Run code in background, then update UI on completion

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-process, timertask

In my app I need to fetch some json data periodically from the internet, then I want to update the UI of my app based on this data. How can I execute a background task and then update the UI on completion? Here are some problems I ran into:

- Using a service/alarm I can't send my json back to the activity
- Using an timer/timertask I can't update the UI because only the thread that created the views may change them
- Using asynctask was working fine but I cannot run it periodically

I have been implementing a listener in my activity that is triggered when the json has been fetched. This seems like a straight forward thing to do, I'm sure there must be a solution!

Comment: why can't your service/alarm send JSON back to the activity? have a look at [ResultReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html)

Comment: Pretty much all your bullets are wrong-  you can return data from a service/alarm.  You can always update the UI from another thread by just posting to a handler that does the actual UI changes.  You can run an AsyncTask periodically.  And you can always just make a Thread as well.  Which is the best way to do it depends on frequency of updates, whether you want to do this while your app isn't in foreground, etc.

Comment: My mistake, I want to update fairly frequently but only while my app is in the foreground; do you know which method would be best for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although adding a Binder between the Activity and the Service would have working, I ended up following [resus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891479/resus)'s answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654982/periodically-executing-asynctask-class-object-updated). It uses a Handler to post a new task in the future in the method that is triggered by the AsyncTask's completion.

This worked well for me because I had already set up a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Using a service/alarm I can't send my json back to the activity, use binder to create connection between Service and Activity, or broadcast to transfer data to trigger ui update